# Global mouse events and fullscreen applications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouseevent, fullscreen

In the application I'm writing I need to be able to register when the user moves the pointer. To do this I have made use of the `NSEvent` class method `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`. This works fine when the program is running in a window on the desktop. However when I make the application fullscreen, by use of the `NSView` `enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:` method, the event handler is no longer called. Could someone explain why this is the case, and what I can do to remedy the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` says it only "receives copies of events posted to other applications".

When your application takes over the entire screen, other applications no longer "see" the mouse movement events.

In other words, you could probably "change over" to using `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` when your app moves to fullscreen.